# Jquery - object has no method 'prop'

Tags: php, jquery, html

My Jquery version is 1.3.2

I am using this below code to select all checkboxes -

```
  $('#alldw').change(function(){
      if($(this).prop('checked')){
          $('tbody tr td input[id="dwchk"]').each(function(){
              $(this).prop('checked', true);
          });
      }else{
          $('tbody tr td input[id="dwchk"]').each(function(){
              $(this).prop('checked', false);
          });
      }
  });
```

But I am getting below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prop' action:181
(anonymous function) action:181
jQuery.event.handle jquery.js:2568
elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

Any solution?

Note - I dont want to upgrade jquery as there are many dependencies on it

Comment: prop is 1.6+. 1.3 is ancient. use attr if you do not want to upgrade

Comment: u need to use the lastest jquery version

Comment: `I dont want to upgrade jquery as there are many dependencies on it` - Then you can't expect to use functions that are only available in newer versions.

Comment: @Kartikeya - Yes they are checkboxes

Comment: I am using same jquery version on my local and it is working

Comment: ids are unique. only one element can match an id selector.

Comment: how can you assign same id to multiple DOM object?

Comment: @D3Systems: Please use the latest ver, as it would be easy and safe in future for you.

Comment: You might also want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514477/upgrade-jquery-1-4-2-to-1-9-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prop is 1.6+. 1.3 is ancient. Use attr if you do not want to upgrade or change to

```
this.checked=true;
```

Your code is very inefficient.  Also ID needs to be unique

```
$('#alldw').click(function(){
  var chk = this.checked;
  $('tbody tr td input[name="dwchk"]').each(function(){
    this.checked=chk;
  });
});
```

You may want to check out the answers to this question

[Upgrade jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514477/upgrade-jquery-1-4-2-to-1-9-1)

Answer (score 1):

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is a added in jquery version 1.6+. you need to use jquery latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your jquery link, it can also be useful for other functions.
Use the below jquery link version for the working of `prop`. You only need to change the **ID's** just, rest everything is fine. And the Jquery will handle everything

[Jquery link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js)

Answer (score 0):

I think the `:checked` Selector is supported on version 1.3:

```
if($(this).is(':checked'))
```

Use it if you don't want to upgrade to a recent version of jQuery because it's an old project and you will have to change a lot of things in it then.