# jquery and upgrading - seeking any extra information

Tags: jquery

We're currently using jQuery 1.4.4 on an e-commerce website.

Lately we've been using a lot of plugins; such as for our menus, lazy loaders, 2 or 3 sliders/carousels etc and A LOT of custom scripting for A/B tests.

I've found that I've started needing to load new jQuery libraries in, and then using noConflict(); make sure that only that section is using this library for certain things.
~(Bonus question): Would upgrading help me not run into so many conflicts?

Now forgive my ignorance, but can anyone tell me IF i should upgrade, what benefits I would presumably get/see, if is it worth the work effort of debugging and troubleshooting? Is it advised if i plan to continue doing a lot more A/B testing and maybe why?

My apologies for sounding noob - I'm reading up on the core upgrade guides etc and it's not making an awful lot of sense.

```
http://winternet.no/articles/jQuery-Breaking-Changes.php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514477/upgrade-jquery-1-4-2-to-1-9-1
https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/08/jquery-2-2-and-1-12-released/
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9
```

etc...

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks all.

Comment: You'll get lots of bugfixes. There have been a small number of incompatible changes, but you may be able to deal with most of them by using the jQuery Migrate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There have definitely been a good bit of changes between vers. 1.4 and the latest version 1.12 (2 is a larger jump for sure as it doesn't even concern itself with older legacy browsers). You can be sure some bit of code on a much older library will kick up problems eventually (1.4 is from 2010). It will also keep you from using the latest plugins and what not easily (see all those noConflicts you're calling). The jQuery Migrate plugin will help a ton in the process of updating. Lastly, it will help keep your code bloat down, cause man it can get messy!