# Jquery 1.9.1 upgrade from 1.6.2

Tags: jquery

my template is designed with JQ 1.6.2,now when i am using the path for 1.9.1 in header along with 1.6.2, obviously function of 1.9.1 is not working, while on removing 1.6.2 template getting destroyed... what the solution of it keeping the functionality of both (1.6.2 & 1.9.1) alive.

Comment: [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Use [jquery migrate plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin)

Comment: Use one or the other. Do not use both.  It shouldn't be too difficult to upgrade to 1.9.1, and you'll have the benefit of using (presumably) better code.

Comment: I answered a similar (but more generic) question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15507363/357774

Answer (score 2):

Palash had the answer http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/ jQuery Migrate should do it.

Comment: Migrate is not possible in this case I think: `It can be used for its diagnostics with versions of jQuery core all the way back to 1.6.4.` or upgrade 1.6.2 to 1.6.4 :)

Answer (score 2):

Before one month, I also felt in same issue. I googled alot but atlast I have added jquery-migrate file, most of the problem get solved.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

Use this snippet of code, may this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the code example. It helped me a lot since I'm new to Jquery

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

```
<script src='jquery-1.6.2.js'></script>
<script>
    var jq162 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src='jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>
    var jq191 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Don't forget to update the rest of your jquery/javascript code to take the right version of jquery.

I agree by the way with Derek, upgrading your template to use 1.9.1 is the best solution. But if you insist using 1.6.x then use the code sample from above.

Some sample code:

```
<script>
    jq191("body").css("color","red");
    jq162("#table").applyTemplate();
</script>
```

Comment: the same way i am using the no conflict..as suggested but still not finding my scripts to run properly  


<script
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var jq164 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    var jq191 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

Comment: Then there is an error in the rest of your script. post that please